# What is the time complexity of following fibonacci series

Tags: time, time-complexity, big-o, fibonacci, pseudocode

I didn't get how its O(n^2)...given in image attached according to me it should be O(n)

```
array[n];
array[0] = 1;
array[1] = 1;
for i = 2 to i = n:
   array[i] = array[i-1] + array[i-2]
return array[n]
```

[image: Fibonacci series]

Comment: this is not C++, if you use a pseudo language remove the tag C++

Comment: Where did you get that attached image from? And yes, It's not correct.

Comment: fibo(0) is 0, not 1. The complexity is O(n) because this is the complexity of the loop. In the picture may be the complexity of O(n²) is about the recursive definition where f(n) = f(n-1)+f(n-2) even the formula is wrong ?

Comment: @bruno But the image uses a loop, not a recursive call.

Comment: Creating and accessing an array should be `O(1)`, not `O(n)` unless, `F` is no array. Maybe it's a linked list that for some reason uses indices and iterates through the whole list to reach a specific index?

Comment: is a typo, picture wanted to say O(2*n) but I disagree on O(N) to create the array if it is not initialized (and there is no reason to initialize it), and fo course when they say O(N) to do `array[i] = array[i-1] + array[i-2]`

Comment: This image is from a coursera lecture about algorithms

Answer (score 0):

The picture you've linked is incorrect. Each iteration of that loop takes time O(1) to execute, and it runs O(n) times, so the cost of that loop is O(n). It looks like the slide accidentally multiplied the O(n) total cost of the loop by the O(n) number of iterations to incorrectly get an O(n<sup>2</sup>) term.

Your analysis is correct - this code does run in time O(n).